# Has anyone developed a PHP based Client for a WCF Service?

Tags: php, wcf, compatibility

Has anyone developed a PHP based Client for a WCF Service? I'm in the process of completing a WCF Service for my work.  Only I don't expect the client to be running on the .Net Stack.  I expect PHP (LAMP) will be the norm.

Are there some obvious pitfalls to avoid?

I'm not running with any security (BasicHTTPBinding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP5 [SOAP extensions](http://www.php.net/soap), check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx) example.